# Creating a PNG file from Python and ensuring some cells are transparent

Tags: python, png, transparency

I am using `Python` to create various maps on a grid from a 2D `numpy array`. The values are either 1 for a road or 0 for the background.

I can export the file into a PNG file by using:

```
matplotlib.image.imsave(filename.png,map_array)
```

The PNG file is created and I can see for example all the roads in one color (yellow) and the background in another color (purple). However I would like all the 1s (roads) to be referenced to a specific color (e.g. red) and the background to be transparent as I am overlaying the map in folium.

How can I make the zero values fully transparent in the PNG and assign a specific color to the 1s for the PNG.

FYI I have tried to change the zeros to nulls (`np.NaN`) but it doesn't seem to work and just makes everything purple.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()` with the argument `transparent=True`, instead of `imsave().`

Documentation here:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html

Here is a short example which uses a 2D numpy array as your image, and nan as the transparent pixels

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create image
image_data = np.random.random((10, 10))

# make some of the values nan. these will be transparent
image_data[3:8, 2:7] = np.nan

# create figure
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image_data)

# save figure with transparent=True argument
plt.savefig('saved_fig.png', transparent=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: matplotlib.image.imsave("output.png",array_name,transparent=True) - unfortunately 'transparent' is not an expected keyword

Comment: Try ```matplotlib.pyplot.savefig()``` instead of ```imsave()```

Comment: Thanks Eric but how do I add the numpy array as the file to plot to the png using savefig()? imsave() uses the numpy directly.

Comment: I edited the response to show how to go directly from numpy array